# Uploading video file to Amazon S3 from an url without having to download the file in java

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload a file from a Zoom recording to Amazon S3. I have the download url but I don't want to download the file in the server before uploading it to Amazon S3 to avoid using all the resources. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the method [`put`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3.html#putObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.io.InputStream-com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ObjectMetadata-) that uses a stream to upload an object on AmazonS3:

> Uploads the specified input stream and object metadata to Amazon S3 under the specified bucket and key name

So basically you can:

- download from zoom as stream
- use this stream as parameter to AmazonS3

In this case you don't need to store locally the file because the stream is redirected to AWS.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I have tried but I was having issues with the file I was downloading (the file size was completely different). I see now that it was because I didn’t have the correct authorizations in Zoom, so it was downloading an HTML page

Comment: For future reference, the video was not downloaded as the url did not contain the access token param